# com.facebook.react.bridge.ObjectAlreadyConsumedException: Map already consumed

Tags: android, react-native, networking, visual-studio-app-center, crashlytics-android

Crash when call promise.resolve, here is my code :

```
  @ReactMethod
  public void get(String url, ReadableMap headers, ReadableMap params, final Promise promise) throws IOException {
    Request mRequest = this.mApiManager.get(url, headers, params);
    mClient.newCall(mRequest).enqueue(new Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        promise.reject(REQUEST_ERROR, e.getCause());
        call.cancel();
      }

      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        inflateData = mUtils.getDataInflate(response);
        promise.resolve(inflateData);
      }
    });
  }
```

This a getDataInflate function :

```
public WritableMap getDataInflate(Response res) {
        try {
            String validJson;
            if (isZipped(res)) {
                final InputStream in = res.body().byteStream();
                Inflater deCompressor = new Inflater(true);
                InflaterInputStream input = new InflaterInputStream(in, deCompressor);
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int length;
                BufferedInputStream b = new BufferedInputStream(input);

                while ((length = b.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                validJson = new String(out.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
            } else {
                validJson = res.body().string();
            }

            mapWrite = mHelper.jsonToReact(validJson);
            mapWrite.putInt("statusCode", res.code());
            return mapWrite;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            mapWrite = Arguments.createMap();
            mapWrite.putString("message", e.getMessage());
        }

        return mapWrite;
    }
}
```

This is jsonToReact function:

```
public static WritableMap jsonToReact(String mJson) {
        WritableMap mWrite = Arguments.createMap();

        mWrite.putString("body", mJson);
        mWrite.putString("message", "Fetch data success");

        return mWrite;
    }
```

I use app center to detect crash log :

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeArray.pushNativeMap
WritableNativeArray.java, line -2
com.facebook.react.bridge.ObjectAlreadyConsumedException: Map already consumed
```

stack trace:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/opVDx.png

My library is RNInflateModule, line 63 call promise.resolve in onResponse that method I post in get() method above. I'm using 0.59.9.

Comment: That looks a bit odd... Can you kindly open a support ticket on portal's chat button? Some additional information would be required to debug this problem.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Can you tell me how to open a ticket on portal's chat button?

Comment: Sure - just open portal, and then go to question mark on top right corner > Contact Support